# Convert image from Jy/sr to Jy/pix

Tags: observational-astronomy, data-analysis

I want to convert the units of an image from Jy/sr (Janskys per steradian) to Jy/pix and I know the pixel scale in arcsec. The way I do this, in python, is the following:

```
from astropy import units

pixel_scale = 0.05 # NOTE: in arcsec

conversion_factor = 1.0 / (units.steradian.to(units.arcsec**2.0) / pixel_scale**2.0)

image_in_Jy_per_pix = image_in_Jy_per_sr * conversion_factor
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

While what you wrote is technically correct, the `astropy.units` package is designed to solve your problem in the following way

```
# use the << operator here instead of * to avoid copying the image
image = image_in_Jy_per_sr << (u.Jy / u.sr)

pixel_scale = 0.05 * (u.arcsec / u.pix)

image = image / pixel_scale ** 2

image_in_Jy_per_pix = image.to_value(u.Jy / u.pix ** 2)
```

Doing it this way allows `astropy.units` to work better, since it allows checking if the result is dimensionally-compatible with Jy/pix.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!